# How to properly create table with 3 columns as primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working with SQL for 3 month, I would like to know create a table with 3 columns as primary key, Any help would be great thank you.

This code below is a Scrip to Create table generated my SQL Server Management Studio of the table

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REP]
(
     [id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
     [id_client] [NCHAR](30) NULL,
     [id_representant] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NULL,
     [date_debut] [DATE] NULL,
     [date_fin] [DATE] NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_REP] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) 
                     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,  
                           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REP] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_REP_id] DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [id]
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all the columns that are part of the primary key have to be not null.

then defining the key just add all columns as comma separated list.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REP](
[id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
[id_client] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
[id_representant] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[date_debut] [date] NULL,
[date_fin] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_REP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [id] ASC,id_client ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In the code above I changed the column id_client to be not null and added it to the definition of the primary key ... ([id] ASC, id_client ASC).

Comment: thank you so much i was missing the ASC, which I dont know what means

Answer (score 0):

To add more columns to a primary Key contraint you'd add the additional fields after the first field.

```
[id] ASC, nextfield ASC, nextfield2 asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a one **composite key** that comprise of more than one primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (
  primary key (id,id_client,id_representer)
);
```